# Proving piecewise function is injective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

**Question:**

[image: Question]

(a) Prove that $f$ is injective.

(b) Compute $ f \circ g$ and $ g \circ f$

**My attempt:**

(a)

Case 1: $ n\ge 0$

We have $ f(n) = 10n+5$

Suppose $ f(a) = f(b)$ where $ a,b$ are integers.

Then $ 10a +5 = 10b +5$ $\implies  a = b$

Case 2: $ n < 0$

We have $ f(n) = -10n$

Suppose $ f(a) = f(b)$ where $a,b$ are integers.

Then, $ -10a = -10b \implies a = b$

Therefore $f$ is injective.

(b)

$f \circ g : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, $\\$ $ f \circ g(n) = f(g(n)) = f(n^{2}) = 10n^{2} + 5$

I am not quite sure how to compute $ g \circ f$

Also,

Whenever we have piecewise functions and we want to prove they are injective, do we look at the separate pieces and prove each piece is injective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part $a$, you should also verify that there is no time when $f(n)=f(m)$ for $n \geq  0$ and $m <0$. This is not bad, since this situation never occurs.

You got the composition correct, but you should say a little more. $n^2 \geq  0$, so $f(n^2)=10n^2+5$ by definition of $f$, or something like this.

Ultimately, these are nit-picks, and if you would prefer to leave these justifications out, that would be okay as well.

$g \circ f$ should be computed piecewise. what is $g(f(n)) $ with $n$ positive? can you compute this? What about with $n$ negative? Then you have a well-defined function everywhere on $\mathbb Z$, and you have indeed computed the composition.

**edit:** I am going to explicitly do the case where $a<0$ and $b \geq 0$. Suppose that $a \neq b$

Note that $f(a)=-10a$. On the other hand, $f(b)=10b+5$. If $f(a)=f(b)$, then we have that $-10a=10b+5$, or that $10(b-a)=5$, which is absurd, since $10$ does not divide $5$. Hence, $a \ neq b \implies f(a) \neq f(b)$.

The  point I was making, is that you do not need the hypothesis that $a \neq b$, all you need is that $a<0$ and $b \geq 0$. If this is true, then $f(a) \neq f(b)$.

If you assume that $f(a)=f(b)$, all you will find is a contradiction, since this can never be the case.

Comment: Whenever we have piecewise functions and we want to prove they are injective, do we look at the separate pieces and prove each piece is injective?

Comment: No, for example, $f(x)=x^2$ for $x \geq 0$ and $f(x)=x^2$ for $x<0$ is technically a piecewise function, but is clearly non-injective. You should check that $x \neq y \implies f(x) \neq f(y)$ for **any** choice of $x,y$ in the function's domain.

Comment: Will $ g \circ f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: Yes. If I give you an integer, and all you do is multiply, add, and square it, it is still an integer.

Comment: Could you please explain more what you mean by : "you should also verify that there is no time when $f(n)=f(m)$ for $n \geq  0$ and $m <0$". I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Yes it should be $ a, b \ge 0$. In the piecewise function there are only two possibilities. Is it necessary to check the case when $ a \ge 0 \ and \  b < 0$?

Comment: For $ a \ge 0$, $ b < 0$ I get $\  f(a) = f(b) \implies 10a +5 = -10b$, but that doesn't imply $ a= b$. Shouldn't this case imply $ a= b$ ?

Comment: But then this case would fail

Comment: I deleted my comments. Please see my edit.